# Probability of an event occuring in a subinterval, given that some number of events ocurred on the interval

Tags: probability, poisson-process

I've just started delving into probability, and I was presented this exercise:

Patients get to a hospital in a mean rate of $5$ patients per hour, following a Poisson process. Given that $13$ patients arrived between $12$PM and $3$PM, what is the probability that $10$ patients arrived between $12$PM and $2$PM.

---

How can I go about solving this?

Comment: Given the number of arrivals, the arrival times of a Poisson process are uniform.

Comment: So i can say that a mean of $\lambda = \frac{13}{3}$ patients arrive between 12pm and 3pm, and then use possion?

Comment: @user: No. $ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $N_{(a,b]}$ for the number of patients that arrive between time $a$ and $b$, where $a$ and $b$ are hours measured from noon. (Adjust the notation $N_{(a,b]}$ to fit your endpoint convention.) You are looking for
$$
P(N_{(0,2]}=10\mid N_{(0,3]} = 13)=\frac{P(N_{(0,2]}=10, N_{(0,3]} = 13)}{P( N_{(0,3]} = 13)}
$$
The event in the numerator can be written as the event $\{N_{(0,2]}=10, N_{(2,3]} = 3\}$, which is an intersection of independent events.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation you used on the numerator. What does the comma imply?

Comment: It's just interval notation: $(a,b]$ is the semi-closed interval of numbers from $a$ to $b$, with $a$ excluded and $b$ included.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not clear enough. I know interval notation. What I'm asking is about $P(X=x,Y=y)$ in the numerator. I've done a google search though and found it means $x$ and $y$. Sorry about the extremely basic questions :p

Comment: Sorry, that comma stands for event intersection, i.e., 'and'.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $X\sim Pois(\lambda _1)$ and $Y\sim Pois(\lambda _2)$ are independents, one can prove that $X+Y\sim Pois(\lambda _1+\lambda _2)$.

Comment: I'm still lost. If we take $X$ to be the patients that arrived between 12pm and 3pm, and $Y$ the patients that arrived between 12pm and 2 pm. Those are not independent right? If we were given that $0$ patients arrived between 12pm and 3pm the probability of $X$ would be $0$. This must mean that neither $X$ nor $Y$ is independent with the initial statement that patients arrive at a mean of $5$ patients per hour. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @user: Take $X_1,X_2,X_3$ i.i.d. $Pois(5)$. What you have to compute is $\mathbb P\{X_1+X_2+X_3=13\}$.